# Electrum transaction, 1 confirmation but i want to cancel it

Tags: wallet, electrum

I sent some bitcoin from my electrum wallet, however i left the mining fee very small so its stuck. But the transaction only has 1 confirmation, i dont want the transaction to go through so is there a way i can cancel it even though it has 1 confirmation. And I also read that after a few days if it isnt confirmed the right amount of times the transaction will jsut cancel so i was wondering how many days would it take to cancel if no miners confirm it.

Thanks.

Comment: How many confirmations does the tx have now?

Answer (score 3):

If a transaction has 1 confirmation then it is in a block. Every ten minutes (on average) it will get another confirmation. It should have 6 confirmations after about an hour.

There is no way to cancel it.